# ExecuteNonQuery is returning a -1 when the query is selecting records. Why?

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

I have cod in a button click that looks like this:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(PubVars.connStr))
     {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '" + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' AND password = '" + txtDelUsrPassword.Text + "'";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connect))
        {
           connect.Open();
           DataRow[] foundRow = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           connect.Close();
        }
     }
}
```

And after I type the line

```
DataRow[] foundRow = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

a red squiggly line is under cmd.ExecuteNonQuery. So when I try to save it and run it The error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Data.DataRow[]'.

What's the cause of this when the query is a standard SQL select?

Comment: Read last comma in the REMARKS section of [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: You are using the wrong method to retrieve data, you should really go look it up.

Comment: You want to execute an SQL query, so you call `ExecuteNonQuery`...what did you think would happen?

Comment: Also you are seriously vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks and are storing passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Because as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery);

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.**

If you wanna get all results and put them in a `DataRow` array, you should use `SqlDataAdapter` for that with [`DataTable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select) method which returns `DataRow[]`.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
   adapter.Fill(dt);
   DataRow[] rows = dt.Select();
}
```

Also you should always use [parameterized statements](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And don't store your passwords as a plain text. Read: [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1054022/447156)

By the way, it is not clear what you will do with this `DataRow[]` but if you *just* wanna check how many results are coming based on your condition in `WHERE` clause, you can change your query as `SELECT count(*)` and use `ExecuteScalar` method to get it.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks. I'm new to C# and I think I know where I went wrong.

Comment: I would recommend a data adapter instead of using a reader and building the rows manually.

Comment: @siride You are right. `SqlDataAdapter` is a better approach in this case. Updated my answer based on that. Thank you.

Comment: Been a while since I used ADO but wouldn't this throw NRE as `dt` is null?

Comment: @DavidG It should since I change it as `var dt = new DataTable();` :) But I don't have a compiler right now so..